# Notes taking app with infinite canvas and ability to move down everything when hit spacebar

Tags: android, note-taking

I am in search of note taking app for android which have following features:

1. Infinite canvas
2. When I hit space bar key at any line to create empty space, it should move below all following images / text / hand (stylus) written / drawn stuff.
3. Descent editing features (something like Samsung Notes)

I did not find any single app having the first two features. Did I miss any?